Reconciling different ideal-theoretic definitions of Hecke Characters
I'm reading Chapter 7 of Neukirch's book on algebraic number theory, where the author defines a Größencharakter (6.1) as:

Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be an integral ideal of the number field $K$, and let $J^{\mathfrak{m}}$ be the group of all ideals of $K$ which are relatively prime to $\mathrm{m}$. A Größencharakter mod $\mathfrak{m}$ is a character $\chi: J^{\mathfrak{m}} \rightarrow S^1$ for which there exists a pair of characters
$$
\chi_{\mathrm{f}}:(\mathcal{O} / \mathfrak{m})^* \longrightarrow S^1, \quad \chi_{\infty}: \mathbf{R}^* \longrightarrow S^1,
$$
such that
$$
\chi((a))=\chi_{\mathrm{f}}(a) \chi_{\infty}(a)
$$
for every algebraic integer $a \in \mathcal{O}$ relatively prime to $\mathfrak{m}$. [Here, $\mathbf{R}\approx\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the Minkowski space of the number field $K$.]

Wikipedia also has an ideal-theoretic definition:

For a number field $K$, let $m=m_f m_{\infty}$ be a $K$-modulus, with $m_f$, the "finite part", being an integral ideal of $K$ and $m_{\infty}$, the "infinite part", being a (formal) product of real places of $K$. Let $I_m$ denote the group of fractional ideals of $K$ relatively prime to $m_f$ and let $P_m$ denote the subgroup of principal fractional ideals $(a)$ where $a$ is near 1 at each place of $m$ in accordance with the multiplicities of its factors: for each finite place $v$ in $m_f, \operatorname{ord}_v(a-1)$ is at least as large as the exponent for $v$ in $m_f$, and $a$ is positive under each real embedding in $m_{\infty}$. A Hecke character with modulus $m$ is a group homomorphism from $I_m$ into the nonzero complex numbers such that on ideals $(a)$ in $P_m$ its value is equal to the value at a of a continuous homomorphism to the nonzero complex numbers from the product of the multiplicative groups of all Archimedean completions of $K$ where each local component of the homomorphism has the same real part (in the exponent). (Here we embed $a$ into the product of Archimedean completions of $K$ using embeddings corresponding to the various Archimedean places on $K$.) Thus a Hecke character may be defined on the ray class group modulo $m$, which is the quotient $I_m / P_m$.

In this paper, near equation (1.11), the authors simply defined a Hecke character as follows (if $L/F$ is a Galois extension of number fields, $G=\operatorname{Gal}(L/F)$, and $C\subset G$ is a conjugacy class):

Let $H \subseteq G$ be an abelian subgroup of $G$ such that $H \cap C$ is nonempty, and let $K=L^H$ be the fixed field of $H$. The characters $\chi$ in the dual group $\widehat{H}$ are Hecke characters.

These definitions seem to be quite different. I know that Hecke characters are most naturally defined in terms of idele class groups, but I do not know anything about class field theory and I would like to stick with the classical definition. How should I reconcile the three definitions? For example, I have some

How are the first two definitions related to the ray class group?

How is the condition "$\mathrm{ord}_v(a-1)$ is at least as large as the exponent for $v$ in $m_f$" in definition 2 reflected in definition 1?

What is definition 3 trying to say at all? Does it have a different notion of Hecke characters?


I am relatively new to these areas, so I would be very grateful if someone could elucidate these technical terms for me. Thanks in advance!!

I thought Neukirch explained the connection between the first 2, no?  For the connection with 3, you need to know (the statements of) class field theory.  This is also in Neukirch.

@Kimball I skipped a few chapters in Neukirch because I'm mostly interested in density theorems. Could you please point me to the relevant statements in class field theory? Also, I think Neukirch explains how the first definition relates to the idele-theoretic one, but I'm not sure if he explains how it relates to the definition on Wiki.

See VI.5.5 or VI.7.2 in Neukirch.  Some other thoughts for references that might be easier to read are Ramakrishnan-Valenza (Fourier analysis on number fields) and Childress's book on Class Field Theory.  (I don't remember if Childress's book says what you want to know about characters.)

@Kimball Thanks for the references. Do you know of any beginner-friendly introduction to class field theory? (Especially for the content that is related to the questions about Hecke characters I'm asking here).

There may be friendlier informal introductions online, but I think Ramakrishnan-Valenza and Childress are good places to learn about the statements of class field theory, and at least the former talks about different perspectives on Hecke characters.  CFT (even just the statements, which is what you want to focus on) takes time to learn, so I don't think you can get too much easier than those references for precise statements.
